# Game Server On Virtualbox (Linux Ubuntu) is not visible from outside

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, gaming

I have started an "**XASH**" server (for Half-Life game) in a **Linux Ubuntu** on **VirtualBox** latest version. (6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2)

- Host machine is runnig Windows 10 Pro 1909.
- I have real IP. (When I start the same server directly on the real
  Windows machine, it is visible.)
- I tried opening ports... On the router I have opened 27015, not sure
  if it's even necessary at all.
- I also tried bridged mode instead of NAT.
- The real machine sees the server over LAN.

Here there are some screenshots:

[Windows VirtualBox settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DglT.png)

[Linux machine screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvNqT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you bridge the VM gets a different ip-address than your Windwos machine. So THAT is the IP address you need to connect to for the game. Not the IP of the Windwso 10 hosts.

When you use NAT the VM uses the same IP as the host and you need to setup port-forwarding.
To my knowledge XASH doesn't need poort 80 at all (and UDP on port 80 is really weird).
But you do need to forward 27015 for UDP and TCP. XASH needs BOTH protocols on that port.

Additonally: You may have to open 27015 (UDP and TCP) on the local firewall in your Linux VM if you are running a firewall there.